# The internet calendar file "abc.ics" does not contain any appointments

Tags: c#, asp.net, icalendar

I have created a .ics VTODO calender, but when I open the file in Microsoft outlook its shows the following error

[image]

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//DDay.iCal//NONSGMLddaysoftware.com//EN
BEGIN:VTODO
CREATED:20070101T000000Z
DESCRIPTION:fdsdsfds
DTSTAMP:20070101T000000Z
DTSTART:20070101T080000
DUE;VALUE=DATE:20070107
DURATION:P5DT16H
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:NEEDS-ACTION
SUMMARY:xxxx
UID:b6709c95-5523-46aa-a7e5-1b5ea034b86a
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
TRIGGER:-PT30M
END:VALARM
END:VTODO
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 1):

VTODO is not supported by Outlook: see Microsoft's spec (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc463911.aspx)