# Outlook says ICS file with VEVENT does not contain any appointments

Tags: outlook, icalendar, outlook-2013

I have an ICS file which I'm using as a test for calendar subscription in Outlook (I'm running Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013).  It contains one VEVENT item and some time zone information (because Outlook in the past complained there wasn't any).  When I last did a subscription to this file about four months ago, everything worked just fine.  Nothing has changed either in Outlook or the ICS file but now I get a message from Outlook saying there are no appointments in the file.  Here are the contents:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:-//utility/NONSGML MSSQLjobs 1.0//EN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
    TZID:Pacific Standard Time
    BEGIN:STANDARD
        DTSTART:16011104T020000
        RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
        TZOFFSETFROM:-0700
        TZOFFSETTO:-0800
    END:STANDARD
    BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
        DTSTART:16010311T020000
        RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
        TZOFFSETFROM:-0800
        TZOFFSETTO:-0700
    END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTSTAMP: 20161130T162354U
    SEQUENCE: 0
    TRANSP:OPAQUE
    UID: 4a5550c6-e06d-44ba-869c-0f4850cfd658@SQL03
    DTSTART:20161202T020000U
    DTEND:20161202T030000U
    SUMMARY: JOB 2
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I have tried using webcal:// and http:// when I specify the URL in the "new Internet calendar subscription" dialog box and it doesn't make a difference.  I also tried importing the ICS file directly as a new calendar and got the same result.  I've also done all of this with a copy of the ICS file which does not include the time zone information and I still get the same message.  I read [The internet calendar file "abc.ics" does not contain any appointments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706099/the-internet-calendar-file-abc-ics-does-not-contain-any-appointments) but that is about a VTODO, not a VEVENT.  Any assistance is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 issues:

- you have an indentation before most properties (but you maybe edited your file before publishing your question),
- in your VEVENT, both DTSTAMP, DTSTART and DTEND have an 'U' terminated datetime, which is invalid. It should be 'Z' terminated if you are looking for UTC time.

As to why it used to work, that is a mystery.